# Storing IOT Data in Azure: SQL vs Cosmos vs Other Methods

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb, iot

The project I am working on as an architect has got an IOT setup where lots of sensors are sending data like water pressure, temperature etc. to an FTP(cant change it as no control over it due to security). From here few windows service on Azure pull the data and store it into an Azure SQL Database.

Here is my observation with respect to this architecture:

Problems: 1 TB limit in Azure SQL. With higher tier it can go to 4 TB but that's the max. So it does not appear to be infinitely scalable plus with size, the query issues could be a problem. Columnstore index and partitioning seem to be options but size limitation and DTUs is a deal breaker.

Problem-2- IOT data and SQL Database(downstream storage) seem to be tightly coupled. If some customer wants to extract few months of data or even more with millions of rows, DB will get busy and possibly throttle other customers due to DTU exhaustion.

I would like to have some ideas on possibly scaling this further. SQL DB is great and with JSON support it is awesome but a it is not horizontally scalable solution.

Here is what I am thinking:

1. All the messages should be consumed from FTP by Azure IOT hub by some means.
2. From the central hub, I want to push all messages to Azure Blob Storage in 128 MB files for later analysis at cheap cost.
3. At the same time,  I would like all messages to go to IOT hub and from there to Azure CosmosDB(for long term storage)\Azure SQL DB(Long term but not sure due to size restriction).

I am keeping data in blob storage because if client wants or hires a Machine learning team to create some models, I would prefer them to pull data from Blob storage rather than hitting my DB.

Kindly suggest few ideas on this. Thanks in advance!!

Chandan Jha

Comment: There's really no objectively-correct answer here - this is more of a broad, opinion-soliciting question on which database to use. This will really be up to you to decide, especially when it comes to your specific query patterns. You also need to decide *what* to store in your database (whether SQL DB, Cosmos DB, or anything else) - you're already storing raw data in blob - do you really need all raw data in your database, or can you work with some type of aggregates? Just food for thought...

Comment: So far you haven't told a thing about what the data is used for. Is the data only visualized, what kinds of queries are performed,what data processing is done etc? Point 3 is talking about long term storage, well: storage accounts are cheap. Have you considered azure time series insight as well?

Answer (score 0):

First, Azure SQL DB does have Hyperscale which is much larger than 4TB.  That said, there is a tipping point where it makes sense to consider alternative architectures when you get to be bigger than what one machine can handle for your solution.  While CosmosDB does give you a horizontal sharding solution, you can do the same with N SQL Databases (there are libraries to help there).  Stepping back, it is actually pretty important to understand what you want to do with the data if it were in a database.  Both CosmosDB and SQL DB are set up for OLTP-style operations (with some limited forms of broader queries - SQL DB supports columnstore and batch mode, for example, which means you could do a reasonably-sized data mart just fine there too).  If you are just storing things in the database in the hope of needing to support future data scientists, then you may or may not really need either of these two OLTP stores.

Synapse SQL is set up for analytics and generally has support to read from data in formats in Azure Storage.  So, this may be a better strategy if you want to support arbitrarily-large IoT data and do analytics/ML processing over it.

If you know your solution will never be above , you may not need to consider something like Synapse, but it is set up for those scenarios if you are of sufficient size.

Answer (score -1):

Option - 1:
Why don't you extract and serialize the data based on the partition id (device id), send it over the to IoT hub, where you can have the Azure Functions or Logic Apps that de-serializes the data into files that are stored in the blob containers.

Option - 2:
You can also attempt to create a module that extracts the data into excel file, which is then sent to the IoT hub to be stored in the storage containers.

Comment: There are *many* options for the OP, but the question is far too broad and opinion-soliciting (and it's a tool/service recommendation question as well). That said: I don't understand why you're suggesting pushing high-frequency data into an Excel spreadsheet. This would be a storage bottleneck and a performance bottleneck, and would introduce several data-processing limitations.